# Get multiple download URL from firebase storage and save them to firebase firestore

Tags: android, firebase, hashmap, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have successfully uploaded multiple selected audio files to firebase storage and i am able to retrieve URLs for all of them. Since i have to upload multiple files, i used for loop for doing that. After uploading files and retreiving the URLs, i want to save them to firestore and here's what i did for doing that.

**Function to upload files**

```
private void uploadAudioFiles(List<Uri> list, final Map<String, String> hashMap) {
        if (list.size() > 0){
            for (int a=0; a<list.size(); a++){
                Uri perFile = list.get(a);
                String filename = getSelectedFileName(perFile);
                final StorageReference audioFileReference = referenceFolder.child("audioClipData/"+filename);
                final int finalA = a;
                audioFileReference.putFile(perFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        audioFileReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                hashMap.put("audioFile"+ finalA, String.valueOf(uri));
                                Log.e("APP_LOG:HashMap(AudioA)", String.valueOf(hashMap));
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

**On save button click**

Below is the code which calls uploadAudioFiles() function.

```
Map<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    String username = name.getText().toString();
            if (!username.isEmpty()){
                progressDialog.show();
                hashMap.put("username", username);
                uploadAudioFiles(audioClipList, hashMap);


                Log.e("APP_LOG:HashMapFINAL", hashMap.toString());
                firestore.collection(currentUser.getUid()).add(hashMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }else {
                name.setError("Required");
            }
```

**Here's the log which i get when i am in uploadAudioFiles() function**

> E/APP_LOG:HashMap(AudioA): {username=Abhi,
>   audioFile0=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp.appspot.com/o/linktofile}

**Here's the log which i get when i am outside of uploadAudioFiles() (ButtonClick) function**

> E/APP_LOG:HashMapFINAL: {username=Abhi}

Now i can't understand why the HashMap is different when i'm in uploadfile function and when i'm outside of the uploadfile function. Is this because of scope of for loop or something else?

can someone help me to understand the situation and solution of the situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's the new code to do what i want!**

```
private void executeUpload(final Map<String, String> hashMap, final List<Uri> uriList) {
        if (uriList.size() > 0){
            spotDialog.show();
                int counter = 0;
                final String firebasePushID = firestore.collection(currentUser.getUid()).document().getId();
                for (int i=0;i<uriList.size(); i++){
                    Uri perFile = uriList.get(i);
                    counter++;
                    final int finalCounter = counter;
                    final int finalI = i;
                    storageReference.child(firebasePushID).putFile(perFile).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                storageReference.child(firebasePushID).getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                            String uri = String.valueOf(task.getResult());
                                            Log.e(LOGCODE, uri);
                                            hashMap.put(fileName, uri);
                                            if (!(finalCounter < uriList.size())){
                                                firestore.collection(currentUser.getUid()).add(hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
                                                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                                            clearFormData();
                                                            spotDialog.dismiss();
                                                            Log.e(LOGCODE, hashMap.toString());
                                                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved data successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        }else {
                                                            Log.e(LOGCODE, Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).getMessage());
                                                            spotDialog.dismiss();
                                                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Couldn't save data! Data seems to be lost in space :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }
                                        }else {
                                            spotDialog.dismiss();
                                            Log.e(LOGCODE, Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).getMessage());
                                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," File uploaded but lost in space :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }else{
                                spotDialog.dismiss();
                                Log.e(LOGCODE, Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).getMessage());
                                Toast.makeText(AddTransaction.this, "Couldn't upload file ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
        }
    }
```

**What i wanted to do?**

First, add the username to hashmap, then uploadAudioFiles and then store the URL of those files to hashmap and then save it to firestore.

**Problem with old code?**

the old code was written to store audioFiles to FirebaseStorage and then store it's URL to firestore but unfortunately, with the old code, it was not happening.

**Reason behind problem**:- firebase APIs are asynchronous and to make everything work properly in sequence, I have to wait until all the files get uploaded and its URL is saved to the hashmap. Since my code was not written to wait for anything, it was just calling the "uploadAudioFiles" function and then without waiting for a response, it used to reach the end of the function. This was the reason why my hashmap was empty. Files were not uploaded till the time I was trying to save hashmap to firestore so hashmap was empty.

**How I solved my problem?**

In the old code, I was calling uploadAudioFunction which used to upload files to the FirebaseStorage but it was not written to save hashmap to firestore. So, I basically re-write the function to handle upload of files as well as handle saving hashmap to firestore. I used a counter variable to count if the for loop has rotated till the end of my list. Using that counter variable, I wrote an if...else condition which says if the loop has rotated required times, then save hashmap data to firestore. This way, I am able to wait until all files are uploaded and their URL is saved to the hashmap.

> Warning:- This is not the best approach. Sometimes hashmap does not
>   include the last file URL but the file gets uploaded successfully. This is all I got for the time right now but I'm still trying to find a new and efficient way to get this done. If you have a better approach then please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase APIs are asynchronous and return immediately before the work is complete.  Your HashMap is going to change over time, whenever the uploads are finished and the download URLs are known.  If you want to know when all the uploads are finished, and all the download URLs are known, you need to pay attention to the Task objects returned by all of them.  Right now, your uploadAudioFiles function is just going to return immediately, before any of the work is complete, and the code that runs after it is not going to see any of the results until some time later.